# Keeping button pressed using sessions in JSP

Tags: javascript, jsp

I coded as screenshot to get data from the MySQL database.

[image]

I added JavaScript codes to change **Accept** button to **Accepted** when clicked and **Decline** button to **Declined** when clicked.

I want to keep those selections in the web page when User opens page again.

How to Implement this functionality?

```
    <script>
       function clickabtn(){
           var el = document.getElementById('btnacc');
           if(el.textContent=="Accept"){
             el.textContent="Accepted";  
           }else{
               el.textContent="Accept";
           }
       }
   </script>

   <script>
       function clickdbtn(){
           var el = document.getElementById('btnde');
           if(el.textContent=="Decline"){
             el.textContent="Declined";  
           }else{
               el.textContent="Decline";
           }
       }
   </script>
```

Comment: You need to store clicked info into db and update the text accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Hey just set value to button like this

```
<script>
   function clickabtn(){
       var el = document.getElementById('btnacc');
       if(el.value == "Accept"){
         el.value = "Accepted";  
       }else{
           el.value = "Accept";
       }
   }
</script>

<script>
   function clickdbtn(){
       var el = document.getElementById('btnde');
       if(el.value == "Decline"){
         el.value = "Declined";  
       }else{
           el.value = "Decline";
       }
   }
</script>
```